# Enviar objeto compuesto a peticion POST

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

tengo una duda que no la puedo resolver. Intento mandar un objeto con otro objeto javascript a un endpoint el cual recibe un Objeto tipo Suscriptor que como atributo tiene un Objeto tipo TipoDocumento, pero el endpoint no recibe el objeto TipoDocumento, el resto de atributos lo recibe perfectamente.
Cual podria ser el problema?
Muchas gracias.

Codigo Javascript

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        suscriptor: {
            Documento,
            Nombre,
            Apellido,
            Direccion,
            Telefono,
            Email,
            Usuario,
            Password,
            TipoDocumento: {
                IdTipoDocumento: 1
            }
        },
    })
}).then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => Swal.fire(res.Msg));
```

Endpoint MVC C# ASP.NET

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GuardarSuscriptor(Suscriptor suscriptor)
    {
        if (SuscriptorBL.GuardarSuscriptor(suscriptor))
            return Json(new Mensaje("Suscriptor guardado correctamente"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        else
            return Json(new Mensaje("Suscriptor ya existente."), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Clase Suscriptor

```
public class Suscriptor
{
    public int IdSuscriptor { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public string  Direccion { get; set; }
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Documento { get; set; }
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public TipoDocumento TipoDocumento { get; set; }
}
```

Clase TipoDocumento

```
public class TipoDocumento
{
    public int IdTipoDocumento { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

Muchas gracias.
Saludos

**Solucionado**
El problema fue solucionado con que la clase TipoDocumento no tenga constructores. Cuando me ocurría el problema la clase tenia dos constructores y supongo que por eso no podría matchear con el parámetro. Le borres los constructores y automáticamente funciono todo correctamente.

Comment: En javascript estás pasando `TipoDocumento: { IdTipoDocumento: 1 }` y en la clase tienes: `public class TipoDocumento
{
    public int IdTipoDocumento { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}` Te estaría faltando el atributo `Tipo`

Comment: Intente con agregarle el atributo Tipo pero no me lo toma. Si mando el objeto sin el atributo TipoDocumento lo reconoce bien, cuando le agrego el TipoDocumento no. No llego a encontrar cual puede ser el problema

Comment: Por favor añade el error que estás obteniendo, no es de mucha ayuda el "no me lo toma"

Comment: No me causaba error, no me tiraba ningún error. Solamente en el parámetro del controlador no cargaba los datos que le mandaba del front. Pero lo logre solucionar, y es muy raro el porque no funcionaba.  Mi clase TipoDocumento tiene 2 constructores y parece que ese era el problema, lo deje sin constructores y automáticamente funciono todo correctamente. No se si tuvieron un problema similar o no. Gracias

Comment: Si lo pudiste solucionar entonces agrega como respuesta a tu pregunta tu solución, asi otras personas con el mismo problema pueden verlo.